# merge a single selector used at two different places to remove scss lint error

Tags: css

```
.pagination .page-link {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.pagination {
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

I have following code i want to merge .pagination with .pagination .pagelink without change of meaning of code and to avoid duplication of selectors  and remove sass lint error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/ for basic nesting.

```
  .pagination {
      justify-content: center;
      margin-top: 50px;
      .page-link{
      white-space: nowrap;
                }
    }
```